# How to do Elasticsearch?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I need to do elasticsearch by using the technologies nodejs, mongodb,
elasticsearch. I need some sample code or tutorial for that. Where can i find the tutorial or examples?

Comment: Pretty sure you have not read the SO guides.....

Comment: do elasticsearch !!! you don't "do elasticsearch", you do search using elasticsearch.

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should research first about the topic. Directly asking such a vague question is not what StackOverflow is about.

Comment: Add something you tried/read that you could not get to work or understand. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

This github link will solve your searching [Nodejs-elastic-mongodb](https://github.com/kristofsajdak/vagrant-fig-nodejs-mongodb-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following link: [integrating elasticsearch with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423759/integration-of-mongodb-with-elasticsearch-in-node-js-environment)

This will give you a basic idea of how to integrate ES with node.